# Is there an online SQL compiler with a multi-table database for practice?

Tags: open-source, sql, postgresql, compiler

I want to practice my SQL.

My first instinct was to install a database management system (such as PostgreSQL), download a well-known database and practice on my local computer.

However, I was wondering if there's a website that has a database with multiple tables and a compiler I can interact with.

Essentially, I want to practice joins, unions, window functions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution.

You can download a .SQL file that creates multiple tables and populates them with data, then open the file using an online complier.

For reference, I wrote [this article](https://medium.com/@arturosbr/easiest-way-to-practice-sql-online-without-installing-anything-a8eb2b12115b) to show others how to do this.

In the article, I download the [Chinook database](https://github.com/ArturoSbr/chinook-postgresql) and open it on [SQLite Online](https://sqliteonline.com/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).